# Obj-c: Allocating a subclassed object from another object and releasing

Tags: object, subclass, release, dealloc, alloc

While profiling my app with Instruments, I found a leak with an array that I allocated.  To my knowledge I was doing this correctly, but it looks like something is wrong.

Let's say I have three classes, class M, A and B.

- Subclass B has a unique NSArray property that is not a part of it's super class A.
- M allocates and instance of subclass B.
- In class M, the instance of subclass B is accessed, and the NSArray property is accessed from that class and allocated.
- In subclass B, dealloc is overridden and has a release for the NSArray, and super dealloc is under it.
- When I release class M, I get a leak for the NSArray object.

My understanding was that I was able to allocate the NSArray object from class M, for example:

```
tempClassB.myNSArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:finalArray];
```

And that I can override dealloc in subclass B to release it's own object that does not exist in it's super class, A. I than can call super dealloc to call dealloc in class A:

```
- (void) dealloc{

    [myNSArray release];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm having is allocating class B in class M will make class M responsible for releasing it. I should allocate the object in class B and release like I am, or put a release in class M's dealloc for the object.